# Azure outbound IP

Tags: networking, azure, ip-address

In Azure, if I were to deploy a Virtual Machine it would "out of the box" have outbound internet connectivity. Is the assumption that the public IP, for the outbound connections of this virtual machine, would be one of the [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) correct?

If I look at the [Public IP addresses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses) documentations it states the following (which strengthens the above statement):

*A resource without a public IP assigned can communicate outbound. Azure dynamically assigns an available IP address that isn't dedicated to the resource.*

So in theory if I create, let's say 100 Virtual Machines, some (or all?) of these Virtual Machines could potentially get the same outbound IP address? Is there any way to make sure that all of these 100 Virtual Machines would be assigned a unique outbound IP address? So that when they access a web service, they could be identified on their unique IP address.

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, by default a VM will be allocated a random IP for outbound traffic, which could result in more than 1 VM having the same outbound IP.

If you want to ensure that you know what a VM's outbound IP is, and for it to be unique for each VM then you would need to create a public IP and assign this to the VM, this will then mean the VM will use that IP for outbound IP's.

There are other ways to fix a VM's outbound IP using Azure Firewall, vNet Gateways, Load Balancers, but this will result in the VM's all using the same fixed IP, which it sounds like is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you Sam Cogan, that confirmed my suspicions that one would need to assign a Public IP per VM, to be able to guarantee a unique outbound IP.